# How to calculate and display a laplacian filtered image

Tags: java, image-processing

I would like to know how to calculate and display a laplacian filtered image for an example Laplacian filter like below..

```
-1    6   -1
 6  -20    6
-1    6   -1
```

Please help me with this. Thank you. I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: We are not a code writing service. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 

We can help with problems if you create a minimal example. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming that you are able to scan image pixel by pixel.*

```
Original_Image(size) =  Result_Image (size) 

for( int i=1; i<Result_Image.rows-1;i++)  // ignore first and last rows to avoid going out of range
{
  for( int i=1;i<Result_Image.cols-1;i++)
{
     Result_Image(i,j)= -20*Result_Image(i,j)+6*(Result_Image(i-1,j)+Result_Image(i+1,j)+Result_Image(i,j-1)+Result_Image(i,j+1))-1*(Result_Image(i-1,j-1)+Result_Image(i+1,j+1)+Result_Image(i+1,j-1)+Result_Image(i-1,j+1));
}

}
```

You can achieve this by using OpenCv for Java or similar image prcocessing libraries for Java if Java itself doesnt support scanning images pixel by pixel .

Note = this algorithm can be inefficent,the libraries have some useful functions for filtering images

Answer (score 0):

You asked about Java, but in case you meant something more basic I will try to answer more generally.

Given a Filter Coefficients (You have an approximation of the Laplacian filter) the way to apply it on an image is [Convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) (Assuming the Filter is LSI - Linear Spatially Invariant).

The convolution can be computed directly (Loops) of in the frequency domain (Using [Convolution Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem)).

There are few things to consider (Real World Problems):

1. The convolution "Asks" for pixels beyond the image. Hence boundary conditions should be imposed ("Pixels" beyond the image are zero, constant, nearest neighbor, etc...).
2. The result of the convolution is bigger then the input image due to the "Filter Transient". Again, logical decision should be made.
3. If you're limited to Fixed Point math, proper scaling should be made after the operation (Rule of Thumb, built to keep the image mean, says the sum of all filter coefficients should be 1, hence you need the scaling).

Good Luck.